# Не запускается java файл - Error: could not open `...\jvm.cfg

Tags: java, cmd

При написании команды в консоли `javac "имя файла"` происходит процесс добавления .class
НО когда я пишу `java "имя класса`, то возникает такая ошибка:
`` Error: could not open `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_251\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg' ``
Помогите разрешить данную проблему.

Comment: А этот файл сам существует - проверяли?

Answer (score 0):

Если ваш файл находится в другой дериктории, то нужно перейти на эту деректорию.

К примеру файл находится на диске D, напишите команду для смены дериктории с C на D:

cd /d d:

Далее напишите путь к этой папке в которой у вас находится файл. В моем случае он находится по этому пути:

D:\IdeaProjects\ezSample\src\com\company

Класс называется Main.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как вы видете мы создали Main.class с помощью javac Main.java. Теперь нужно выйти из папки com.company (вместо company можно поставить название вашей компании) и скомпилировать с помощью:

java com.company.Main

В итоге получаем скомпилированную программу в консоли. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
P.s. сам сталкивался с такой проблемой и нашел такое решение.

Answer (score 0):

Решил данный вопрос посредством переустановки java и jdk. Была проблема в неправильном сохранении файлов.